# Upload youtube video with JavaScript is not working on FF

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, upload

upload_video.html sample(https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript) may not working with Firefox 60.0.1.

When I tested this sample on other browsers, there was no problem.
However, I tested it on FF 60, I met a problem: after uploading video file to server, response from youtube is not JSON, but html of upload_video.html.

I set breakpoint on line 217 of cors_upload.js:

```
216: MediaUploader.prototype.onContentUploadSuccess_ = function(e) {
217:    if (e.target.status == 200 || e.target.status == 201) {
```

e.target is:

> target: XMLHttpRequest
>
> ​​​mozAnon: false
>
> ​​​mozSystem: false
>
> ​​​onabort: null
>
> ​​​onerror:bound ()
>
> ​​​onload:bound ()
>
> ​​​onloadend: null
>
> ​​​onloadstart: null
>
> ​​​onprogress: null
>
> ​​​onreadystatechange: null
>
> ​​​ontimeout: null
>
> ​​​readyState: 4
>
> ​​​response: "\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\t…"
>
> ​​​responseText: "\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\t…"
>
> ​​​responseType: ""
>
> ​​​responseURL: "http://mydomain/path/null"
>
> ​​​responseXML: null
>
> ​​​status: 200
>
> ​​​statusText: "OK"
>
> ​​​timeout: 0
>
> ​​​upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
>
> ​​​withCredentials: false

Is this a bug, or my mistake?

Comment: A firefox addon occurs this problem. No problem after disabling that.

Comment: Not problem of google api. Add-on program occurred this.